# InDesign: how to choose which artboards to import from AI file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, artboard, file-placing

I have about 10 artboards in my Illustrator file I need to link to in InDesign. I want to use a single Illustrator file to place my content rather than export each artboard separately. This will help me cut down on the amount of files. How can this be done?

I go to place the artboard in InDesign, but it defaults to the same artboard each time.

Answer (score 7):

Import using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (not drag & drop) and tick the "Show Import Options" check box. That will open up some options where you can choose which specific artboard to place. This is indeed useful to keep multiple vector assets into a single AI file, thus reducing the number of linked files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW--that particular keyboard shortcut is for the "Place" command, which is found in the File menu (on a Windows machine, at least).  I am not very good at remembering keyboard shortcuts, so I thought I would throw that out in case you had the same trouble.

Comment: I try to place (I'm on a mac) and it pulls up a dialog where I can arrow through my artboards but then when I pick it just defaults to the first artboard. Maybe the problem is I haven't renamed my artboards.

Comment: @JohnDrach On the Mac, depending upon which OS version and which version of InDesign you are using, you may have to actually **click** the "OK" button. Hitting the "enter" or "return" key may simply place the first artboard, ignoring your selection in the Preview pane. I'm not certain if that's an ID bug or an OS bug... but I've seen it often before.

Comment: Double check your artboards, normally this shouldn't happen. You're probably missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to re-save your .ai file as an Illustrator 2020 (or newer, if you are reading this when a new file format is announced).  I was having the same issue, however, the option to see other "pages" (artboards) was not available.  After doing a Save-As over the original file, the option showed to choose the artboard from the Place File dialogue box appeared.